Misunderstanding of "before" in Cypress
i'm new to Cypress and i'm trying to test my home page.
The before and beforeEach functions don't work the same way that Cypress describes in my project. According to Cypress:
before(() => {
  // root-level hook
  // runs once before all tests
})

beforeEach(() => {
  // root-level hook
  // runs before every test block
})

describe('Hooks', () => {
  before(() => {
    // runs once before all tests in the block
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    // runs before each test in the block
  })

I want to load my webpage once and then run several tests on it without it reloading between tests. A root level test like so:
before(() => {
  cy.visit("localhost:3000");
});

describe("Home header Elements", () => {

  it("should have a heading in main header", () => {
    // code
    );

it("test 2",() => {
// code
}
  });


What ends up happening is that it only visits localhost for the first test and then succeeding tests fail because there's no website to visit. The result is still the same when i place the before function inside the describe block.
Now i'm forced to use beforeEach. When i place it outside of the describe block, as Cypress documentation said above, i expect there the tests to visit localhost in every test/describe block. But it runs on every test.

So before every it test, the webpage and this is very time consuming.
When i place it inside a describe test block, it only runs within that block which is what i expect.
Is there something that i'm missing perhaps in my configuration? I'm using Cypress 10.6.0, even when i try to update, this is what i get. The aim is to load once and test that one page.

This question is similar to: How to synchronize the test execution within one file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Looking at the log you provided, one problem is that you are trying to use one test per command, which is what you normally do in a unit test situation.
For end-to-end testing you can consider combining the common Home page tests into a single test.
The reason an individual test is slow is that Cypress sets up a queue of commands for each it() block and includes in the queue and before() and beforeEach() blocks that apply. In addition, there is also code for retrying failed tests applied to the it() block.
Since each command is logged to the runner and report, it's not really necessary to be so granular with your test structure. You can easily see which command fails (when it does) so your best strategy is to combine the steps like this:
it('Home header elements', () => {
  cy.visit(...)
  cy.get(<main header>)
  cy.get(<sub heading>)
  cy.get(<join button>)
  cy.get(<hire button>)
  ...
})

This approach has "fail-fast" characteristic, if cy.get(<main header>) fails then the other steps are not attempted.

You can set Test Isolation - suite-level override for a particular describe() block of tests to save having to rebuild the state of the page for a sequence of tests.
Expanding your example,
console.clear()

before(() => {
  console.log('before - spec root or support/e2e.js')
})

beforeEach(() => {
  console.log('beforeEach - spec root or support/e2e.js')
})

describe('1st test group - testIsolation OFF', {testIsolation: false}, () => {
  before(() => {
    console.log('\n1st group - before - inside describe context')
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('1st group - beforeEach - inside describe context')
  })

  it('test 1.1 opens the page', () => {
    console.log('test 1.1')
    cy.visit('http://example.com');
  })

  it('test 1.2 checks details of the page', () => {
    console.log('test 1.2')
    cy.get('h1')
  })
})

describe('2nd test group - testIsolation ON', () => { // testIsolation on by default
  before(() => {
    console.log('\n2nd group - before - inside describe context')
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('2nd group - beforeEach - inside describe context')
  })

  it('test 2.1 opens the page', () => {
    console.log('test 2.1')
    cy.visit('http://example.com');
  })

  it('test 2.2 re-visits page', () => {
    console.log('test 2.2')
    // need to re-visit here for success!
    cy.visit('http://example.com');
    cy.get('h1')
  })
})

The first group sets {testIsolation:false} and allows this group to visit the page in the 1st test and continue to make assertions in the 2nd test.
(Only one example, you can load the page in the before() that is within the 1st describe).
I also added console logs so you can see the order that different hooks run WRT to the tests.



I want to load my webpage once and then run several tests on it without it reloading between tests.

This is the core of what is causing your issues, as it is conflict with Cypress' Test Isolation.

As stated in our mission, we hold ourselves accountable to champion a testing process that actually works, and have built Cypress to guide developers towards writing independent tests from the start.


We do this by cleaning up test state and the browser context before each test to ensure that the operation of one test does not affect another test later on. The goal for each test should be to reliably pass whether run in isolation or consecutively with other tests. Having tests that depend on the state of an earlier test can potentially cause nondeterministic test failures which makes debugging challenging.

So, with the default value for Test Isolation (enabled), Cypress will clean up the browser context, which includes "shutting down" the browser. While it is possible to disable Test Isolation, I would strongly encourage you not to do that and instead look at the reasons why you feel that you should only launch the webpage once and then run several tests on it.
Could you use cy.session() to expedite setting data on launching the webpage? If there are network calls that are slowing down navigating to the page that could be mocked out via cy.intercept()?
